# a couple of basic python logging questions

Tags: python, logging

I'm working through [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html), [logging docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), and [tomordonez/logging tutorial](https://www.tomordonez.com/python-logging-tutorial.html) to get a handle on the logging system. When I add logging to a Class, the logging info doesn't show up for `MyClass.__init__()` but it does show up for `MyClass.obj_name()`. Why is that?

How do I include the Class name with the `funcName` info in the logging output? The docs and other SO questions I read looked like I might need to write a custom formatter? Or something like that? Are there any non docs.python.org sites with detailed walk-throughs, something in between basics and advanced? Thank you!

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# # create file handler which logs debug messages
# fh = logging.FileHandler('output.log.txt')
# fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# # create console handler which logs debug messages
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
# fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
# # add handlers to logger
# logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)


class MyClass():
    def init():
        logger.info('creating an instance of MyClass object')

    def obj_name(self):
        logger.info('declare name')


def main():
    myobj = MyClass()
    # print(dir(myobj))
    myobj.obj_name()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Complete output:

```
PS D:\0_program_dev>'C:\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'd:\0_program_dev\hands_of_ada_book_generator\logging_tools.py'
    application obj_name - INFO - declare name
PS D:\0_program_dev>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help:

```
import logging
from functools import wraps
import sys
stdouthandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
                    handlers=[stdouthandler])


def status(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug(f"hello {func.__name__}")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

class MyClass():
    @status
    def __init__(self):
        logging.debug(f"created instance of {self.__class__}")

    @status
    def my_function(self):
        logging.debug(f"here is a function {sys._getframe().f_code.co_name} of {self.__class__.__name__}")


my_obj = MyClass()
my_obj.my_function()
```

> 2018-12-08 22:43:40,503 DEBUG: hello **init**
>
> 2018-12-08 22:43:40,503 DEBUG: created instance of class '**main**.MyClass'
>
> 2018-12-08 22:43:40,503 DEBUG: hello my_function
>
> 2018-12-08 22:43:40,503 DEBUG: here is a function my_function of MyClass

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! The simple wrapper you provided is very helpful since wrappers are still very new to me. Your code works completely. Only question left is why the `init()` logging comment doesn't show up in my code.

Comment: Nevermind on the `init()`. Question was answered. Thank you!

Comment: The wrapper by JBB works, but is there a way to add the Class name to _every_ debug statement? Adding `{sys._getframe().f_code.co_name}` to every debug call seems excessive but for debugging seeing the class_name.function_name would be really helpful.